# Binary data storage with layers and eviction policies

Tags: c#, windows, storage

I'm looking for a solution for binary data storage and before developing it thought someone might know of something that would fit my needs

1. Windows OS
2. C# API
3. Storage layers which data can be added to
4. Ability to move data from one layer to another, based on time added
5. Reserve space on disk for a layer
6. Eviction policy for a layer e.g. Age or priority on data, circular buffer
7. Persistent
8. Time series data

It will be holding video, audio, sensors and custom data events

I have looked around, but been unable to find anything, but find it hard something like is does not exist.

Comment: Similar in principal, but needs to persist and will get very large. I.e it wil hold video, audio and other data streams

Answer (score 0):

With some support from your code our [Solid File System](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/) (Application Edition) will do the job, I think, with one exception - there's no way to reserve space for future other than allocating a file of given size and when the space is needed deleting the file and putting real data.